# asp core исключить свойство модели из ответа клиенту при определенных условиях

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Хочу написать атрибут для модели данных, который проверяет роль пользователя и атрибут может запрещать или разрешать отдавать клиенту некоторые свойства модели в зависимости от его роли.

Применение атрибута может выглядеть так:

```
class Product
{
    public Id {get; set;}
    public Name {get; set;}
    [AllowForAspRole("Admin")]
    public Price{get; set;}
}
```

И если пользователь не администратор то на запрос к контроллеру, действие контроллера, которое возвращает данную модель вернет все свойства модели кроме Price

Я прошу лишь направить меня, куда мне копать. Я думаю мне нужно поймать момент, когда возвращаемая из контроллера модель превращается в строку ответа

Или может уже в коробке это есть?

Comment: можно создать разные вью - модели, можно использовать рефлексию, а может и есть что-то из коробки

Comment: Из вопроса не совсем ясно про mvc. Интуитивно я предполагаю что вы используете mvc подход в своем приложении, но в вопросе вы ничего про это не написали, от выбранного типа приложения зависит ответ.

Comment: Прошу прощения! Использую asp.core web api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложно:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters
Объявляем свой фильтр. Фильтр-атрибут вешаем на нужный контроллер / действие,
проверяем ответ. Если тело ответа - ваша модель, то модифицируем ее (меняем на Dictionary или анонимный объект), убирая ненужные поля. Ненужность определяем наличием атрибута и неисполнением метода проверки из него (добавляем в него метод, который вернет TRUE/FALSE).

Просто:
Объявляем поля Nullable и в том месте, где мы их получили, просто ставим NULL вместо значения, если условие ложное.
И настраиваем сериализатор, как то так - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486694/2822609

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея! Я ещё хочу вот так попробовать https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters

Comment: М, я хотел написать этот вариант - но не стал. Там есть много нюансов реализации. Кстати, возможно так будет даже проще реализовать предложенный мною первый вариант. Удачи!

Comment: Да и плюс в том, что можно контролировать, для каких контроллеров применять. Спасибо за ответ.